# Why can't I bind and reuse a haskell lens like a normal variable?

Tags: haskell, lenses

(I'm using lens-family, not lens)

I have a fairly deep data structure and I need to focus on two parts that have a common path. So very intuitively I define `_table` with the intention to reuse it:

```
let _table = _sOutput.at (O.tName table)._Just'
tp' <- evalCacheable (_table.O._stPerm) M.empty
... reuse _table
```

but this yields an error:

```
Could not deduce (Functor f0) arising from a use of ‘_sOutput’
from the context (MonadReader (EvalConf State All) m, ...
```

Yet, directly pasting the value of `_table` into the argument works:

```
tp' <- evalCacheable (_sOutput.at (O.tName table)._Just'.O._stPerm) M.empty
```

What is going on? I can give more details about the types involved, but to me this seems puzzling regardless. I was under the impression that

```
let x = y
z <- f x
```

was equivalent to

```
z <- f y
```

in all cases.

Comment: This could be related to the Monomorphism Restriction. Try putting `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` at the top of your file.

Comment: it worked! someone on #haskell also solved it by adding an explicit type signature to _table. according to him Rank2Types was messing with type inference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be related to the Monomorphism Restriction. Try putting `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` at the top of your file. –[randomusername](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538101/why-cant-i-bind-and-reuse-a-haskell-lens-like-a-normal-variable#comment49149700_30538101)

It worked! Someone on `#haskell` also solved it by adding an explicit type signature to `_table`. according to him `Rank2Types` was messing with type inference. – [BruceBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538101/why-cant-i-bind-and-reuse-a-haskell-lens-like-a-normal-variable#comment49149911_30538101)